# Bring Debian to second Position in the GRUB Menu at startup

Tags: debian, grub2

So, I currently have BOSS Linux and I am going to install debian (currently installing right now)

And I want my older OS (BOSS linux), on the first position and the debian, (freshly installed) to be on the second. Please tell me how to do that